Booting issue with Ubuntu 24.04
After I updated my Ubuntu to the latest version I cannot boot the system fully.


What brand/model system? What video card/chip? What version of Ubuntu, 24.04.1 would be latest. Any older may cause issues. Is UEFI & SSD firmware latest version?
